# Which Paypal API Version should I use. (Classic vs. REST)

Tags: paypal

I have a site which tracks time spent working on projects for clients. It was created in classic Asp.  I want to bill the time to the clients using the PayPal API. I am having a hard time determining which version I should use. I have read much of documentation and I am not sure which API to use (Classic vs REST).

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is "whatever works for you/your requirements". If you've read the documentation the REST API doesn't fully map to Classic API (yet). So, if any of your requirements aren't supported in REST, then the choice is made for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still prefer the Classic API.  The REST API is still new to PayPal and is well behind the Classic API in terms of overall features.